# How do I position a div to upper left of page?

Tags: css

I am struggling with a CSS issue. I have a simple front page that consists of 4 divs. 3 of which are visible. The other is an overlay.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="overlay" visible="false"></div>
<div id="container">Container</div>
<div id="menu">
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="button" class="button" value="Go" onclick="ajax.getData()" />        
</div>  
</form>
```

I want the the "menu" to be positioned to the left of the header. I have been able to accomplish this by setting this div's position absolute:

```
 #menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #666;
    background: #ffffff;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

However, when the screen is resized (smaller) this div remains locked in position but the other divs resize (desired) but the menu div does not. Changing the positioning to be 'relative' causes the div to fall beneath the 'container' div. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my CSS?

The results are the same in IE and FF.

Thanks!

-Nick

Comment: You've specified both a width and a height for `#menu` so it's not going to change sizes. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm not expecting this div to overlap the others as the screen is re sized.

Comment: I guess I will use percentages rather than explicit px sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three ways you can address this.

Method 1: - Change div order

```
<div id="header">
<div id="menu">   ---- Menu here
<div id="overlay">
<div id="container">
```

... and the float-left the header and the menu, both relative. Having non-floated block elements between these would otherwise affect the relative floating and the divs wouldn't necessarily line up.

Method 2: - float everything

```
<div id="header">
<div id="overlay">
<div id="container">
<div id="menu">
```

... where everything is float-left, position relative. You need to however ensure that the width of header + overlay + container isn't too much to push you menu to the next line.

Method 3: Absolute positioning AND resizing

Keep things as they are an add `position: relative` to your form CSS. This way the absolute-positioned div inside the form will interpret the form as it's parent element and re-size within it. Your menu div however cannot re-size according the form width currently because it has fixed pixel dimensions. These need to be percentages for it to re-size.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nick, no probs. There's probably even more ways to get that done but only playing around with it can tell.

Answer (score 0):

use float: left; on the menu then clear the "float" by using clear: both; right after.

```
<div id="menu" style="float: left;">
 <input type="text" />
 <input type="button" class="button" value="Go" onclick="ajax.getData()" />        
</div>  
<div id="header" style="float: right;">Header</div>
<div style="clear: both;" />
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="container">Container</div>
```

Comment: Floating on the div doesn't have an effect the div is still at the bottom of the page (not the top right) when not absolutely positioned.